# using IF function based on multiple cells that then imports values from completely different cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

For this example I'm working in the tab "Math". What I would like to do is that if any of these columns' values ("O", "S", "W", "AA", AE", "AI", "AU", "AY", "BC", BG", "BK") are "0" or "1", then columns D-J of the same row would import into the tab "MATH ANALYSIS".

You can see that AU9 has a value of "0", so I would want D-J of row 9 to import into the MATH ANALYSIS tab, and what would be even better is if I could also then have a column there that indicates the column header for that column, so that I know which column has the 0 or 1. In this case AU is PA alignment_score, so I'd love it if I would get D-J and then some identification of that column, like could it read the value of "AU2"?

I've put the values into the MATH ANALYSIS tab that I would want to see, based on the values of row 9.

Can this be done??

[This is the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nnxma9UdX_zVHkIOC_F4fwwylkzvf7gB_nmdZDR4Bq0/edit#gid=1074862250).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `query()` function. Usually you would use conditions like `S = 0 or S = 1 or W = 0 or W = 1` but there would be a lot of repetition, so in this case it may be easier to coerce the numbers to text and use pattern matching instead, like this:

`=query(Math!A2:BK, "select D, E, F, G, H, I, J where O matches '0|1' or S matches '0|1' or W matches '0|1' or AA matches '0|1' or AE matches '0|1' or AI matches '0|1' or AU matches '0|1' or AY matches '0|1' or BC matches '0|1' or BG matches '0|1' or BK matches '0|1'", 1)`

See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nnxma9UdX_zVHkIOC_F4fwwylkzvf7gB_nmdZDR4Bq0/edit#gid=265630034) sheet in your sample spreadsheet for an illustration, and the [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343) help page for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to add on to doubleunary's answer to get the second part of what I was hoping to do, by simply adding the columns to the "select" part of the query.

I've added it to the original test sheet.

=query(Math!A2:BK, "select D, E, F, G, H, I, J, **O, S, W, AA, AE, AI, AU, AY, BC, BG, BK** where O matches '0|1' or S matches '0|1' or W matches '0|1' or AA matches '0|1' or AE matches '0|1' or AI matches '0|1' or AU matches '0|1' or AY matches '0|1' or BC matches '0|1' or BG matches '0|1' or BK matches '0|1'", 1)